# Duda sobre almacenamiento en memoria

Tags: c++, c

Según me explicaron, todo se guarda en memoria dependiendo de tu arquitectura: (32 bits/64 bits). Ocupando todo una **palabra**, allí viene mi duda, sé que un entero ocupará las cuatros casillas en 32 bits porque es del mismo tamaño que una palabra (4 bytes), pero en el caso de un **short**, ¿también ocupará las cuatro casillas, a pesar de solo necesitar una o dos?

Comment: El tipo de dato `short int` ocupa  2 bytes.

Comment: Sí, lo sé, pero viendo una imagen de mi material de apoyo, en un sistema de 64 bits con ocho casillas, introducen un entero que ocupa las ocho, casi todos repletas de 0 para completar, a pesar de que un int solo ocupe 4.

Comment: Las CPU suelen acceder a direcciones alineadas, normalmente coincidentes con el tamaño de palabra. Si intentas leer *desalineado*, en realidad se realizan 2 lecturas. Por tanto, es mas rapido leer 8 bytes y quedarnos con 2, que leer 2 veces 2 para quedarnos con 4.

Comment: Un CPU de 64 bits significa que **puede** operar con enteros de 64 bits con una sola instrucción (no por partes). Igual puede operar con submúltiplos (32 bits, 16 bits, 8 bits).

Answer (score 2):

Debido a que el hardware está optimizado para leer una palabra (del tamaño que corresponda a la arquitectura podría ser 32 o 64 bits, por ejemplo) los compiladores de C/C++ agregan bytes en cero (padding) para que los tipos de datos más chicos queden alineados al tamaño de una palabra. También puede que el hardware tenga operadores para mover un tamaño predeterminado de bytes, como [MOVE16](http://68k.hax.com/MOVE16), y entonces convenga alinear las variables a 16 bytes.

Esto implica que efectivamente se utiliza más memoria de la que pensamos si nos limitamos a leer el tamaño de la variable declarada sin tener en cuenta el alineamiento. Además dependiendo del compilador podemos intentar controlar el comportamiento con sintaxis extra:

```
int x __attribute__ ((aligned (16))) = 0;
```

En GCC podemos usar esta expresión para pedir que el compilador alínea la variable x en 16 bytes. Con esta expresión sólo podemos pedir que se alínea a una cantidad de bytes mayor que la alineación por defecto. Si queremos, en cambio, reducir la alineación al mínimo podemos escribir:

```
byte x __attribute__ ((packed));
```

Y entonces quedará alineada a un byes. Pero hay que tener en cuenta que esto afectará la performance del programa.

Comment: Oh, estupendo. ¿Eso explicaría el porqué un tipo de dato double (8 bytes) entraría en un sistema de 32 bits?